# Dropbox to sync *nix home folders

Tags: linux, sync, dropbox

I'm using a Linux machine at work, and started using at home in a VM for some home development.

I have a vimrc and a bashrc with some configuration, that are useful for both machines.

What is the best way to sync them? Create a symlink for each file in my home folder pointing out to a the respectives files in my Dropbox sync folder? Is this possible (delete .bashrc and create a symlink instead)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Dropbox does support symlinks and you can use these to sync files which are outside of the "My Dropbox" folder. The Dropbox folder on my Ubuntu box is all symlinks.

See http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Sync_Other_Folders

Comment: That's fine, but I can't work out how to then sync the same directory structure on another computer...

Answer (score 5):

What you suggest should be fine, just store the .bashrc and other configuration files in your drop box then symlink ~/.bashrc to your one in your drop box.

Answer (score 3):

Dropbox is a great way to store your vimrc and bashrc.  Its a great place to store *all* of your important dotfiles, actually.

I use another approach than the suggestions above.  I have moved many of my dot files to a git repo on my dropbox account.  The repo also contains a little script which, when run, will move or delete actual dot files in a home directory, and replace them with symlinks to my dot files in the git repo.

Because I'm using revision control, I can incrementally experiment or tweak my dot files over time. I can also revert any changes I make if I screw something up.  I can also create branches - Sometimes I like to experiment with and tweak a vimrc or muttrc downloaded from the net, etc.

Comment: Wait, you have a git respitory in you Dropbox folder, and you commit to it?

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox is great for that, and yes it support symlinks. 
this new beta, might be a big help, with selective sync, to keep some files on only one computer.
http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=20472